# Next.js 13: How to apply different Layer to a certain page?

Tags: next.js

I have a `app` folder like this:

```
/app
  page.tsx
  layer.tsx ... toplayer 
  /subpge
    page.tsx
    layer.tsx ... sublayer
```

and I would like to apply `sublayer` to `/subpage/page.tsx` without applying `toplayer`, but I have no idea how to achieve this. Is there any solution for this? Thanks.

c.f.: I naievely tried this solution but it did not work.
[Next.js 13 - Have different shared layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212962/next-js-13-have-different-shared-layouts)

Answer (score 0):

You can create directory with parentheses around to group your routes. Read more at: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#route-groups